# How do I make my two-dimensional array show horizontally as well as vertically in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to make a two-dimensional array that generates a random number from 0-50. It works but it doesn't generate a 3 by 5 layout with columns and rows.

I've tried changing around the i and the j and using different variables.

```
/**
     * Constructor for objects of class GenerateLithium
     */
    public GenerateLithium()
    {
        randomGenerator = new Random();
    }

    public void generateSample()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                tray[i][j] = i * j;
                tray[i][j] = grading++;
                grading = randomGenerator.nextInt(50);
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
    }
```

```
    public void printTray() 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                System.out.println(tray[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
```

Result Now:

```
45

22

11



23

1

35



45

43

22



13

15

3



0

16

42
```

Expected Result:

```
45 
22 
11

23 
1 
35

45 
43 
22

13 
15 
3

0 
16 
42
```

Comment: Change `println` to `print`. The `ln` part means "new line", i.e. to start a new line after the print, and that's what you don't want.

Comment: Change to `.print(` in `System.out.println(tray[i][j] + " ");`.

Comment: Don't add linebreaks?

Comment: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tray).replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", ""));`

Comment: On your question you say: 3 by 5 layout with columns and rows. While on your expected results there is a single column. Please update your question

Comment: Thanks i got it now it was the println

Answer (score 1):

```
public void printTray() 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(tray[i][j] + "/t ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the first `System.out.println` with `System.out.print` inside `printTray()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to show output of array 2D as Grid layout:

```
public void printTray()
{
    for (int[] x : tray) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a full GenerateLithium class that prints a 3 x 5 table.

```
class GenerateLithium{
    Random randomGenerator;

    int[][] tray = new int[5][3];
    int grading;

    public GenerateLithium() {
        randomGenerator = new Random();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        GenerateLithium m = new GenerateLithium();
        m.generateSample();
        m.printTray();
    }


    public void generateSample() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                tray[i][j] = i * j;
                tray[i][j] = grading++;
                grading = randomGenerator.nextInt(50);
            }
        }
    }

    public void printTray() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                System.out.print(tray[i][j] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
0   8   14  
29  33  20  
18  37  10  
33  21  2   
8   45  29
```